# Angular 6 - display string as titlecase and remove special chars

Tags: angular, filter, pipe

I have the following code to display text with titlecase pipe.

```
{{person.name| titlecase}}
```

I would like to add a filter/pipe that removes special chars from the string. Only stay with numbers and letters.

For example:

"john doe" will be "John Doe".

"@@johN doe1!!$" will be "John Doe1".

Answer (score 1):

Here is one take on a custom `AlphaNumPipe`:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'alphaNum'
})
export class AlphaNumPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string): string {
    return value.replace(/[\W_]/g, '');
  }

}
```

Note `\W_` is a negation of `\w` regex which is shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9]` i.e. all alpha numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own pipe that do just that,

by using

> ng generate pipe my-pipe

and use a simple regex replace

```
  export class MyPipePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return  value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "");
  }

}
```

you should read more about creating [custom pipes in here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)